# ssh reverse tunnelling access local web server from internet

Tags: apache-httpd, ssh-tunneling, webserver

Hi have local web server running on the locahost, **localhost:8765** and I need to access this server from outside network. Also I have public server running  ssh server and Apache server both.

I have found the revers ssh tunnelling with reverse proxy server to access the website. Belw is the command I used

```
 ssh username@test.ddns.net -R 3000:localhost:8765
```

And in public serve for Apache revers proxy I made the setup like.

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf**

```
    ProxyPass /rpi http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse /rpi http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

And my public serve address is

```
https://test.ddns.net:8090
```

And I can access the tunnelled local web server with `https://test.ddns.net:8090/rpi` but the problem is the java-script and css not loading. That is the links are not working. When I check browser console I can see the errors.

```
GEThttps://test.ddns.net:8090/static/css/jquery.timepicker.css
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 316ms]

GEThttps://test.ddns.net:8090/static/css/ui.css
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 539ms]

GEThttps://test.ddns.net:8090/static/css/main.css
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 606ms]
```

How can resolve it.

Comment: I might misunderstand something, but it is strange that you configure http URLs in Apache although you use https to access the web server. Also, I would try to access the web server and the CSS URLs manually from outside the server and from the server itself and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your local machine, your webapp is at the root path, i.e. you can access it at:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

But, when you set up the reverse proxy, you are configuring `/rpi` path (not root) to forward to your tunnel.  The Javascript and CSS files are trying to load from the root (as it is configured on your local machine, but remember, you are only forwarding requests at `/rpi`, so the js and css requests at root are not going through your rev proxy.

To fix this, move the webapp on your local webserver to `/rpi`, i.e. the same path that you intend to use via your rev proxy.  Now all requests will go through the tunnel correctly.  To test this, you'll want to make sure you can access your webapp locally at:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/rpi
```

Then reconfigure your reverse proxy to in:

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf**

```
ProxyPass /rpi http://127.0.0.1:3000/rpi
ProxyPassReverse /rpi http://127.0.0.1:3000/rpi
```

Now you should be able to visit your site at `https://test.ddns.net:8090/rpi` and all content should load correctly.